# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n k(3k-1)=n^2(n+1)$

Tags: induction

Let me type the whole question:

> Prove that $1\cdot2+2\cdot5+3\cdot8+ \cdots+n(3n-1)= n^2(n+1)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$

If you have a link for online-documentary for induction methods and examples please post it here it would be really useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not search for how to do induction yourself, and then tell us where you get stuck?

Comment: Go through the basics. Did you prove the case $n=1$? Write it explicitily. Then, suppose it is true for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ Write this. Now, consider the case $n+1$. The left side gives you $1*2+\dots+n(3n-1)+(n+1)\left(3(n+1)-1\right)$. How would you use your hypothesis to get to the right side?

Comment: I proved it for $k=1$, then assumed $k$ is true and tried it for $k+1$. I just write the sigma notation but I don't have any clue how can I simplify the equation.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes easier to start by the end

$$(n+1)^2(n+2)-n^2(n+1)=$$

$$(n+1)\left((n+1)(n+2)-n^2\right)=$$

$$(n+1)(n^2+n+2n+2-n^2)=$$

$$(n+1)\left(3(n+1)-1\right)$$

qed.

Comment: This isn't really 'starting by the end', This is just the regular inductive step. I (+1'd) none the less.

Comment: Ok as you want friend of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Let P(n) be the conjecture, $$\sum_{k+1}^{n}(k(3k-1))=n^{2}(n+1)$$

Assume true for n = 1
$$ 1 * 2 = 2 $$
$$ 1^{2}*(1+1) =2 $$
Therefore, P(1) is true

Assume true for P(i), for n = i

$$\sum_{k=1}^{i}k(3k-1) = i^{2}*(i+1)
$$

Show that conjecture is true for P(i+1) for n = i+1
P(i+1) = P(i) + U(i+1), where U(n) is the nth term

$$i^{2}*(i+1) + (i+1)(3(i+1)-1)$$
$$=(i+1)*(i^{2}+3i+2)
$$
$$=(i+1)(i+2)(i+1)$$
$$=(i+1)^{2}(i+2)
$$
$$=(i+1)^{2}((i+1)+1)$$

Hence, P(1) and P(i+1) are true when P(i) is assumed to be true. Hence, the conjecture is true.